# Kafka - Topology change on redundant apps

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say I have two applications with the same applicationId "foo-processor" and the following setup:

```
    streamsBuilder.table(fooTopic)
                  .groupBy(...)
                  .reduce(...)
```

Assuming I now have some cases I don't want to handle and add a filter like this:

```
        streamsBuilder.table(fooTopic)
                      .filter(...)
                      .groupBy(...)
                      .reduce(...)
```

During deployment, not all instances of the app is shut down and restarted at the same time. Therefore, instance #1 of foo-processor is restarted and instance #2 is still using the previous topology. What happens is that instance #1 will have this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Assigned partition foo-processor-KTABLE-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000006-repartition-2 for non-subscribed topic regex pattern; subscription pattern is foo-processor-KTABLE-REDUCE-STATE-STORE-0000000007-repartition|<topic>
```

I assume this is the expected behaviour because the repartition topic might not contain the same events because of the different topology. That being said, I am wondering how should I handle change in topology.

- Does that mean that the application is different so the applicationId should also change? If not, how should I handle topology changes if many instances of the same app are running?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the topology, you need to use a new `application.id` -- running both in parallel with the same `application.id` is not supported.